# video data in opencv

Tags: c++, c, opencv, video-capture

Can anybody please tell me in what format the video data is saved in opencv, after decoding it by ffmpeg. I mean if it is saved as a matrix then is it 8bit/pixel kind of thing? If anybody can provide some documents or link explaining in details will be a great help. I also tried to google but couldn't find something related.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the video format is chosen by the user [OpenCVWiki: VideoCodecs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs). By the way that took about 3 seconds to find with google. Remember to research before asking.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.But I wanted to know, is it saved in a matrix format or something like that? the above link doesn't really describe what I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitive reference to examine is probably the code itself! Look at the function `CvCapture_FFMPEG::open` in the file `modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp`. This method is called by, for example, `cvCaptureFromAVI()` and `cvCaptureFromFile()`. The code excerpted below clearly gets the width and height from the file, but it ignores the input bit depth and always uses a packed 8:8:8 bit RGB representation of the video in memory (as indicated by the `PIX_FMT_BGR24` constant):

```
#if LIBAVFORMAT_BUILD >= CALC_FFMPEG_VERSION(52, 111, 0)
    int err = avformat_open_input(&ic, _filename, NULL, NULL);
#else
    int err = av_open_input_file(&ic, _filename, NULL, 0, NULL);
#endif

    .......    

#if LIBAVFORMAT_BUILD >= CALC_FFMPEG_VERSION(53, 3, 0)
    avformat_find_stream_info(ic, NULL);
#else
    av_find_stream_info(ic);
#endif

    .......    

    avpicture_fill( (AVPicture*)&rgb_picture, rgb_picture.data[0],
                    PIX_FMT_BGR24, enc->width, enc->height );
```

Further evidence that this is the case is provided by the following code in `CvCapture_FFMPEG::retrieveFrame`:

```
img_convert_ctx = sws_getCachedContext(
                NULL,
                video_st->codec->width, video_st->codec->height,
                video_st->codec->pix_fmt,
                video_st->codec->width, video_st->codec->height,
                PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                SWS_BICUBIC,
                NULL, NULL, NULL
                );
```

Looking at the ffmpeg documentation, the `PIX_FMT_BGR24` in this call specifies the *destination* pixel format, i.e., what will be handed off to opencv.

Comment: thanks alot..I will check the ffmpeg document and get back to you if I have some more doubts.